# what file extension do i use with nskeyedarchiver

Tags: iphone, xcode, archive, nskeyedarchiver, saving-data

I am writing an app that uses NSKeyedArchiver to save its data.
Should my file be ishotTrack.plist or ishotTrack.arch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The archives created with NSKeyedArchiver are binary property lists, so it makes sense to use *plist* file name extension. On the other hand they aren't human-readable, so opening the plist won't help anybody much.

Comment: I had some experience with this recently, and XCode was happy to open the plist files in question and display them in its familiar key-value table format.